# melhor nome para esse metodo em php

Tags: php

Estou com duvida em qual nome colocar no metodo em PHP abaixo:

```
    public function checkbox($idForm)
    {
        $list = $this->v->getAllInAssocArr();

        foreach ($list as $key => $val) {

            $isRel = $this->v->isRel($idForm, $key);

            if (self::isPost($key) && !$isRel) {
                $this->v->insert($idForm, $key);
            } 

            
            if (!self::isPost($key) && $isRel){
                $this->v->delete($idForm, $key);
            } 
        }

    }
```

Ele add ou remove Dados no DB conforme os posts selecionados
no checkbox do formulario.
pensei em colocar "*updateCheckboxByIdForm*" mas ele nao atualiza

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "ele nao atualiza"? Vc pode colocar o nome que vc quer. Na minha opinao, "updateCheckboxByIdForm" significa nada melhor que o nome original. Se depende do formulário por ser "checkbox_inscricao" ou "checkbox_cliente" etc...

Comment: sobre "nao atualiza" . Eu quiz dizer que o metodo nao foi feito para atualizar os dados. apenas "insere" ou "remove" por isso achei estranho colocar "update ..." como nome para o metodo ...

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seja bem vindo. Acredito que o nome **updateCheckboxById** como você mesmo citou seja um bom nome.

Eu sempre costumo seguir um padrão de iniciar verbalizando o que irá fazer , seguido do objeto mais a ação daquele método:

**Ex**: getUserClear()

```
    public function updateCheckboxById($idForm)
    {
        $list = $this->v->getAllInAssocArr();

        foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
            $isRel = $this->v->isRel($idForm, $key);
            if (self::isPost($key) && !$isRel) {
                $this->v->insert($idForm, $key);
            } 
            if (!self::isPost($key) && $isRel){
                $this->v->delete($idForm, $key);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: vlw! obrigado josé :)

Comment: Qq coisa é só avisar!